# How to Open tables in EDIT/INSERT mode in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I tried to open my tables in Delphi with the following code:

```
for I := 0 to  Datamodule1.ComponentCount - 1 do
  if Datamodule1.Components[I] is TADOTable then
  Begin
    TADOTable(datamodule1.Components[i]).EDIT;
  End;
```

But when I want to post it gives me an error that the tables is not in EDIT or INSERT mode. What have I done wrong here?

Comment: You don't *open tables in EDIT/INSERT mode*. You open the tables. When you want to edit or insert, you *then* call Edit or Insert, set the field content, and call Post. If you're in Edit/Insert mode and scroll the table, it automatically Posts any changes and takes the table out of edit/insert mode. You should find a Delphi database tutorial (like the one in the documentation) to learn the basics.

Comment: Ok maybe I explained wrong here. I want to open the table in Edit mode to modify the data. After I edited the data on the form(s). I call a similar procedure to post the data.

Comment: The answer is still the same. *You don't open tables in insert/edit mode.*. Read my previous comment again.

Comment: I think you've missed the point of what @KenWhite is saying.  You **can't** open a dataset "in edit mode".  You have to open the table first, which puts it into browse mode (DataSet.State = dsBrowse), then call DataSet.Edit to put it into edit mode.  Once you've done the edit, you should call DataSet.Post (which osts the changes and leaves it in browse mode again) **before** you call DataSet.Close.

Comment: Is your table OPEN/Active?  Is your table connected to a TADOconnection and the ADOConnection is connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback. I have managed to solve the problem. Before i set the table in the edit mode state, I firts check the state, as I have already put the table in edit state before calling this procedure

```
for I := 0 to  Datamodule1.ComponentCount - 1 do
 if Datamodule1.Components[I] is TADOTable then
  Begin
     if not (TADOTable(datamodule1.Components[i]).State in [dsEdit]) then
       TADOTable(datamodule1.Components[i]).EDIT;
  End;
```

Comment: You don't seem to be taken any notice of the comments from several people about needing to open a table before you can edit the data in it.   Your "answer" should at least say how you are addressing that.

Comment: I want to open the table in edit state. The table was open to browse and I found the record I want to edit. The answers above is known to me and gave me no assistance. I think I have expressed my quetion wrong and thus dit not get the answers I was looking for. I also found (while debuging) that the table in question was already in the edit state, and when i want to put it in edit state again delphi got confused. Thus inserting the extra "if not" command have solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

One sample of standard code is like this:

```
// open the table
ADOTable1.Open;  // Mode = dsBrowse
// Enter in Edit mode
ADOTable1.Edit;   //Mode = dsEdit
// Change field values
ADOTAble1.FieldByName('NOM').AsString := 'Lou';
...
// Try to save
try 
  ADOTable1.Post;
except
  // Capture the error
  // Show Message
  //...
end;
```

See help for methods:  **Post**, **Cancel**, **Edit**,...  of **TDataSet**.

It's simple to adapt this sample code to your working code.

Regards.