# Edit/Insert mode error: Directly after tblbookings.edit

Tags: database, ms-access, delphi

I'm working on my end year project for high school and this problem came up. This code is supposed to filter the database and only work on the data whose ID is bigger than intGroep2 (which is at this point 22). Then it must change the first row's 'pop' column to the value of cb501pop1.checked.

```
  tblbookings.Open;
  tblbookings.Edit;

  tblbookings['pop'].edit;

  tblbookings.filter := 'ID >= '+ inttostr(intGroep2);
  tblbookings.filtered := true;
  tblbookings.First;
  tblbookings['pop'] := cb501pop1.Checked;
```

The problem arises with the following line:

```
tblbookings['pop'].edit;
```

If it is not there, the program gives me an error: 'dataset not in edit or insert mode.' And if it is there it gives me an 'invalid variant operation' error.  One other question said to change "edit"  to append, but it still gave the same error. Another question suggested that somebody posted already, which I didn't. Nowhere in my code is 'post'. This is supposed to be an easy answer and thus should only be practicing the basics. 'Afterscroll' and other stuff mentioned in other questions isn't supposed to be in the solution since we didn't learn it yet.

Thank you.

EDIT: `tblbookings.fieldbyname('pop').edit;` gives an error: missing operator.

Comment: Try ( ) in place of [ ]. Consider this example I found in another answer: `ADOTAble1.FieldByName('NOM').AsString := 'Lou';`

Comment: @June7 no it gives me a missing operator error?

Comment: I edited my comment perhaps after you read it. Edit question to show your exact attempt.

Comment: The example I found does not even show an Edit method on the field, only the table. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32824523/how-to-open-tables-in-edit-insert-mode-in-delphi

Comment: I think you should do what you are supposed to do when asking for debugging help, namely provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  What is it exactly that you are trying to achieve with your 2 calls to .Edit, to change an existing record or insert a new one or what?  Then, what are you trying to do with the filter?  Btw, sorry to say so, but I am astonished that this q has been upvoted.

Comment: Btw, I am not sure where you are getting your code from but `tblbookings.fieldbyname('pop').edit;` is meaningless in Delphi because the Edit method operates on the current row of the table, not an individual field.  Once you have put the table into edit mode, you can change any or all of the current record's fields.  Immediately after you've done setting the edited field value(s), you should call the table's Post method (in some circumstances you can get away with not doing that, but it is bad practice and asking for trouble).

Comment: Also btw, I think you would do far better to google yourself a Delphi dataset-editing tutorial (there are many) than trying bits of code borrowed from here and there without any proper understanding of how to to it.

Comment: Your code makes no sense. First, you try to call `Edit` on a single field, which is both invalid and unnecessary. Second, you go into edit mode, then filter the table (which takes  it out of edit mode because it changes the position of the record pointer), then call `First` (which again would take it out of edit mode), and *then* try to edit the record, which  a) not the one you were on when you called edit, and b) the table is no longer in edit mode because you've performed two operations that would take it out of edit mode. Find a Delphi DB programming tutorial instead of floundering.